# How to convert varchar to tinyint

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert my table in sql server from php, but I don't understand how to fix it form my query. When I try running my query an error appears that informs me that I can't convert my datatype.

Like this :

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1 CASE When 1 = 1 Then Default ELSE Piority + CONVERT (Varchar(5),1) END' to data type tinyint.
```

This is all my php code.

```
<?
 include "new.php";

  $ID_Person                =  $_POST['IDPerson']; 
  $Number_Phone_Person  =  $_POST['NumberPhonePerson']; 
  $Piority_Phone_Person =  $_POST['PiorityPhonePerson'];
  $Default              =  'Default';
  $Piority              =  'Piority';



   $response            =  array();

   if (isset($ID_Person)                &&
isset($Number_Phone_Person)     &&
isset($Piority_Phone_Person)    
) 
   {

$query      = "INSERT INTO T_Person_Phone
                (
                ID_Person, 
                Number_Phone_Person, 
                Piority_Phone_Person

                )
                VALUES 
                (
                '$ID_Person',
                '$Number_Phone_Person', 
                '$Piority_Phone_Person
                CASE When $Piority_Phone_Person   = 1  Then  $Default 
                ELSE $Piority + CONVERT (Varchar(5),$Piority_Phone_Person) END');";

$hasil      = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query,$response);
    if($hasil)
{   

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User successfully created.";

}   else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Eksekusi error.";    
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

   }    else 
   {
    $response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Data gagal disimpan.";
    }
// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you're encapsulating your SQL statement with quotes, so it is interpreting that whole string literally. That is to say, MySQL doesn't think you want a `case` switch, but literally a string containing those words. Inserting a string into a tinyint column is invalid, and hence the error.

So change this:

```
'$Number_Phone_Person', 
                '$Piority_Phone_Person
                CASE When $Piority_Phone_Person   = 1  Then  $Default 
                ELSE $Piority + CONVERT (Varchar(5),$Piority_Phone_Person) END')
```

To this:

```
'$Number_Phone_Person', 
                CASE WHEN $Piority_Phone_Person = 1 THEN  $Default 
                ELSE $Piority + CONVERT (Varchar(5),$Piority_Phone_Person) END)
```

Note I'm not entirely sure what is going to happen with your whole `$Piority + CONVERT (Varchar(5),$Piority_Phone_Person)` - that statement may be just as invalid.

Comment: it show Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Default'. what means that?

Comment: "Default" isn't a valid value for a tinyint column either. You'll want to actually input the valid number. Being that you're using string replacement, I would change your `$Default = 'Default'` line to `$Default = 0` or whatever you want it to be. One thing to note as well, variables like this are usually lower case. Capitalized variables tend to "mean" something else.